# Determining when the android MediaController view becomes visible

Tags: android, android-videoview, mediacontroller

I'm using the MediaController class to anchor the video controller views to my VideoView. When the VideoView is clicked,the controller becomes visible for some few seconds then leaves the screen. Is there a listener in the MediaController that allows us know the moment it becomes visible or not?

Answer (score 1):

`android.widget.MediaController` is inherited from `android.view.View`, so that you can add [android.view.View.addOnAttachStateChangeListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#addOnAttachStateChangeListener(android.view.View.OnAttachStateChangeListener)) for attach state changes.

```kotlin
mediaController.addOnAttachStateChangeListener(object : View.OnAttachStateChangeListener {
    override fun onViewAttachedToWindow(view: View?) {
    }

    override fun onViewDetachedFromWindow(view: View?) {
    }
})
```